# hapi-auth-cookie not overwriting default tll

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I am using the plugin for an API REST using hapi 16.6.2 and hapi-auth-cookie 7.0.0. I set the keepAlive : true in the plugin initialization. In the login controller I have a "remember me" parameter which sets the ttl (request.cookieAuth.ttl) for 15 days. This is not posible as the keepAlive function overwrites with the default ttl.

Code sample, you can use the example on the plugin page https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie/blob/v7.0.0/example/index.js

You just have to add keepAlive and ttl on plugin register

```
server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', true, {
    password: 'password-should-be-32-characters',
    cookie: 'sid-example',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    isSecure: false,
    keepAlive: true,
    ttl: 15 * 60 * 60 * 1000
           ...
```

and use the ttl method on the controller, i.e:

```
if (remember) {

    request.cookieAuth.ttl(15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 

}
```

If the remember me is checked by the user, set the cookie duration to 15 days. This will not be set, instead the default 15 min is used. ¿Am I missing something? ¿Is not the right approach for a remember me?